# In AS3 Error #1069: Property systemResult not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Im newbie to integrate Flash,php and mysql using xamp. I tried alot to rectify this bug but i cant do so because i dont knw whether the bug is in php page or the value is not passed to php.

This is my AS3 code :

```
public function processLogin ():void {


            trace("inside the processlogin method");

            var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("controlpanel.php");         
            phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;          
            var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;           
            phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

            phpVars.Username = Username.text;
            trace(phpVars.Username);
            phpVars.password = password.text;
            trace(phpVars.password);
            phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;
            trace("phpvariable"+phpVars);
            phpLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);

        }

        public function showResult (event:Event):void {             
            trace("show result");           
            result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;      
            result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
            trace(event.target.data.systemResult);  
        }

    }
```

This was the Output in console:

```
sucess
now im in checklogin
inside the processlogin method
raj
raj
phpvariableUsername=raj&password=raj
starts process login method
show result
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property systemResult not found on String and there is no default value.
    at actions::main/showResult()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Corresponding Php page is

```
<html>
<body><?php 
include("connect.php");
 $username = $_POST['Username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$Username' AND password='$password'");
$login_counter = mysql_num_rows($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
$userbio = $data['user_bio'];
print "systemResult=$userbio";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all - `event.target.data` is a string - which has no property `systemResult`.

Just take a look into `event.target.data`, this should be the html code of the response.

Comment: I cant able to fix this u have any idea how to get $userbio into flash. this holds the users details... and this was set in **target.data.systemResult** this shows undefined value

Comment: 1st: The U in $Username must be in lowercase$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$Username' AND password='$password'");
2nd: if you do: trace(event.target.data) does it write "systemResult=..."?

Comment: ...i changed username in lowercase. now i have a doubt whether this systemResult carrying my userbio data to flash. This is my question. Thank you very much